# The convergence of the sequence $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3-a_{n}}$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

The sequence $\{a_n\}$ is defined by $a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3-a_{n}}$ for each $n\ge 1$ and $0<a_{1}\le2$. Prove that $\{a_n\}$ converges.

---

My strategy is to apply the *Monotone Convergence Theorem*. So far, I have proven that $a_{n}$ is bounded. How can I show the monotonicity? I guess that it depends on $a_{1}$.

Another question: Is there any other method to show that $\{a_n\}$ converges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in stating that the monotonicity is dependent on $a_1$. Therefore, we will distinguish between three cases. Define $c=\frac{3}{2}-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$.

1. Suppose that $0<a_1<c$. Then, if we assume that $0<a_n<c$, we see that
   $$
   a_{n+1}=\frac{1}{3-a_n}<\frac{1}{3-c}=c.
   $$
   Also, clearly, $a_{n+1}>0$. So, by induction, $0<a_n\leq c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Now, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, we see that
   $$
   a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{3-a_n}-a_n=\frac{1-3a_n+a_n^2}{3-a_n}=\frac{(a_n-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{5}{4}}{3-a_n}.
   $$
   Note that $a_n-\frac{3}{2}<c-\frac{3}{2}=-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{5}$, such that $(a_n-\frac{3}{2})^2>\frac{5}{4}$. Also, $3-a_n>3-c>0$. So,
   $$
   a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{(a_n-\frac{3}{2})^2-\frac{5}{4}}{3-a_n}>0,
   $$
   since both the numerator and the denominator are greater than 0. We conclude that $a_n$ is monotonic increasing and bounded from above, and thus converges.
2. For the second case, assume that $c<a_1\leq2$, and use the same reasoning as above to find that in this case, $a_n$ must be bounded from below by $c$, and that $a_n$ must be monotonic decreasing, to conclude that $a_n$ must therefore converge.
3. Finally, the case that $a_1=c$, gives $a_n=c$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which does indeed converge.

We conclude that $a_n$ converges for all $0<a_1\leq 2$.

Answer (score 1):

You could prove it, through the proving that it is bounded and decreasing.

Lets prove that it is bounded. Obviously if $0<x\leq 2$ you can see that $\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{1-x}\leq 1$. Now suppose that $\frac{1}{3}<a_n\leq 1$ then clearly $0<a_n\leq 2$ and therefore $\frac{1}{3}<\frac{1}{3-a_n}\leq 1$ and we get $\frac{1}{3}<a_{n+1}\leq 1$.
Therefore by induction I proved that it is bounded between $0$ and $2$.

Now lets prove that it is decreasing.

Suppose that $a_n>a_{n+1}$. Then $-a_n<-a_{n+1}$ and therefore $0<3-a_n<3-a_{n+1}$ and so $\frac{1}{3-a_n}>\frac{1}{3-a_{n+1}}$ which means that $a_{n+1}>a_{n+2}$ and by induction we reach that it is decreasing.

So it converges. Lets call its limit $L$. We will have $L = \frac{1}{3-L}$ then $3L - L^2 - 1 = 0$ and one of its roots are our aim.

$$L = \frac{-3+\sqrt{5}}{-2}<1,\qquad L = \frac{-3-\sqrt{5}}{-2}>1$$
So
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Comment: Actually it's decreasing. In your proof by induction you did not consider the base case.

Comment: Thank you! I altered it

Comment: @HamidShafieAsl I think you miscomputed the roots for $L^2-3L+1=0$.

Comment: @AnCar Yes I was in hurry, I made mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

We show by induction that $a_n\in [\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2},\tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}]$ for $n\geq 3$.

Clearly $a_3$ satisfies this property by assumption since $a_2\in(\tfrac{1}{3},1]$ and then $a_3\in(\tfrac{1}{2},\tfrac{3}{8}]$. Clearly $\tfrac{1}{2}>\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ as $\sqrt{5}>2$.

So now assume that $\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\leq a_n\leq \tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Then $\tfrac{1}{3-\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}} \leq a_{n+1}\leq \tfrac{1}{3-\tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}}$ which means $\tfrac{2}{3+\sqrt{5}}\leq a_{n+1}\leq \tfrac{2}{3-\sqrt{5}}$ and by looking at conjugates, we see that $\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}\leq a_{n+1}\leq \tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, which completes the induction.

With these bounds we can prove that the sequence is decreasing.

Note that $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ is equivalent to saying $a_n\geq \tfrac{1}{3-a_n}$.

Consider the equation $x\geq \tfrac{1}{3-x}$. This is equivalent to the degree two inequality $x^2-3x+1\leq 0$. This inequality holds if and only if $x$ is between the roots of the equation $x^2-3x+1=0$. These roots are precisely $\tfrac{3\pm \sqrt{5}}{2}$.

Thus we have that the condition $a_{n+1}\leq a_n$ is satisfied for all $n\geq 3$, so the sequence is decreasing and bounded, so it converges.

As computed before, its limit can only be $\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$ or $\tfrac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. But the latter is bigger than $\tfrac{3}{8}$, which was an upper bound for $a_3$ and we know that the sequence decreases for $n\geq 3$. Thus the limit must be $\tfrac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.